# Putty Access Denied

Tags: raspbian, access-point, putty

[image]

https://youtu.be/F5OYpPUJiOw

Hi, I follow this youtube link but I have problem with Putty Access Denied. I am a newbie and just started learning how to setup Raspberry Pi 4 with LAPTOP only.

Please advise.

Comment: "I follow this youtube link" explain what YOU did. DO NOT post pictures of text post TEXT

Comment: that video is 2 years old. Things have changed since then. Refer to e.g. the official docs about the various options to write and configure PiOS

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post